# Including STXXL library in the MakeFile

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, stxxl

I was trying to install STXXL library to a custom path following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34312041/937153) answer supplying prefix to `cmake` this way:

`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr . && make all install`

When I run the tests, they seems to be working fine. But I want to include STXXL in a different MakeFile and compile that project. In that MakeFile there a line

`STXXL_CONFIG     = /opt/stxxl/stxxl.mk`

I believe the configuration file `stxxl.mk` comes from the old `make` based installation (I couldn't locate it in my system either). I was wondering how I can modify this file to include STXXL library and get the custom project compiled.

Without modifying the above statement in `MakeFile`, I am getting the error:

`undefined reference to 'stxxl::get_next_seed()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

It goes without saying that I don't have root access and unfortunately, neither a good background with MakeFiles. This is not a duplicate of [Makefile with STXXL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9558648/937153)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a third party C++ library from a non-standard location in GNU Make the regular steps are:

1. Add the path to 3rd-party library headers to your C++ preprocessor flags. E.g.

   ```
   CPPFLAGS += -I/3rd-party/include
   ```
2. Add the path to 3rd-party shared/staric library to your linker flags and the library itself. Assuming the library is named `lib3rd-party.so` or `lib3rd-party.a`, e.g.

   ```
   LDFLAGS += -L/3rd-party/lib -Wl,-rpath=/3rd-party/lib -l3d-party
   ```